# Python __getitem__ and in operator result in strange behavior

Tags: python, python-3.x

What explains the following behavior:

```
class Foo:
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        print("?")
        return 1

f = Foo()

1 in f  # prints one ? and returns True

5 in f  # prints ? forever until you raise a Keyboard Exception

# Edit: eventually this fails with OverflowError: iter index too large
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If an object doesn't have a `__contains__` implementation, `in` falls back on a default that basically works like this:

```
def default__contains__(self, element):
    for thing in self:
        if thing == element:
            return True
    return False
```

And if an object doesn't have an `__iter__` implementation, `for` falls back on a default that basically works like this:

```
def default__iter__(self):
    i = 0
    try:
        while True:
            yield self[i]
            i += 1
    except IndexError:
        pass
```

These defaults are used even if the object is not intended to be a sequence.

Your `1 in f` and `5 in f` tests are using the default fallbacks for `in` and `for`, leading to the observed behavior. `1 in f` finds `1` immediately, but your `__getitem__` never returns `5`, so `5 in f` runs forever.

(Well, actually, on the reference implementation of Python, the default `__iter__` fallback stores the index in a C-level variable of type `Py_ssize_t`, so if you wait long enough, that variable maxes out and [Python raises an OverflowError](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.0/Objects/iterobject.c#L60). If you saw that, you must be on a 32-bit Python build. Computers haven't existed long enough for anyone to hit that on a 64-bit Python.)

Comment: Regarding the OverflowError, I ran this on both 64 and 32 bit, and you are right I only saw it on 32 bit.

Comment: Do you happen to know of the documentation that explains this? I would like to read up on why this implementation was decided.

Comment: @Matthew [Expressions > Membership test operations](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-details), also [object.__contains__](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__) and the paragraph right above it

Comment: @MatthewMoisen: These defaults were the original behavior of `for` and `in`, predating the introduction of `__iter__` and `__contains__`. See the Python 1.4 documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/release/1.4/ref/ref5.html#HDR16) and [here](https://docs.python.org/release/1.4/ref/ref7.html#HDR2).